# Vim9: How will '#' characters be handled in colors/* files now?

Tags: colorscheme, vim9

Vim9 now interprets '#' as the start of comment, but I use this character in color setting files.
For instance:

```
hi Todo guifg=#d14a14 guibg=#1248d1 ctermfg=red ctermbg=darkblue
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is only a problem if you [decide to use vim9 syntax](https://vimhelp.org/vim9.txt.html#Vim9-script). You can keep using the old syntax indefinitely if vim9 is inconvenient for you (but you will give up some performance improvements).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In vim9 comment starts with either `space+#` or beginning of the line and `#` (as far as I remember). So your color setting would still work.

1. `:h vim9`
2. `/Comments starting<CR>`

```
To improve readability there must be a space between a command and the #
that starts a comment: >
    var name = value # comment
    var name = value# error!
```